# C# more elegant replacement for foreach-search

Tags: c#

Here is the entirety of a method inside a class:

```
public Foo GetFooByInfoName(string name)
{
    Debug.Assert(name != null, "name is not an optional argument");
    foreach (Foo f in storedFoos.Values)
    {
        if (name.Equals(f.FooInfo.Name))
        {
            return f;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have obviously changed the names, so assume FooInfo is required and Name can't simply be a property of the class Foo.

Is there a more elegant way to write this method? I'm not very familiar with C# but I feel like there's an extension method or something which can turn this method into a 2-liner.

Note I'm looking for readability, it's not a contest to reduce the number of lines. I simply think the method would be more clear if C# had a way to search for the named `Foo` in one line.

(I'm using C# 3.5)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`return storedFoos.FirstOrDefault(f => name == f.FooInfo.Name);`

You'll need to make sure that your are `using System.Linq`.

By the way, C# overrides the == operator for strings, so it's usually easier to use == instead of .Equals (much more readable, and idiomatic C#).

Comment: Regarding the == overloaded operator on strings: what StringComparer is used ?  OrdinalCaseSensitive/CaseInsentive - CurrentCulture ...  I find it clearer when being explicit.

Comment: I think by default it uses the current culture. If you need to compare using a different culture, then you need to using string.Equals and pass in the culture as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered LINQ ?

```
storedFoos.FirstOrDefault( f => name.Equals (f.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq:

```
var foo = storedFoos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == f.FooInfo.Name);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) to write it like this:

```
public Foo GetFooByInfoName(string name)
{
    Debug.Assert(name != null, "name is not an optional argument");
    var f = storedFoos.Values.Where(x => x.FooInfo.Name == name)
                              .FirstOrDefault()//gets the first value or null
    return f;
}
```

Note: Make sure you have a `using System.Linq` on the top.

Comment: Know your API: storedFoos.Values.FirstOrDefault( x => x.FooInfo.Name == name) is much clearer, and has the same result.